# multi socket architecture with asio

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, client-server, boost-asio

I have a Client - Server architecture with 10 Servers with permanent connections with a single Client, the software is written in C++ and uses boost asio libraries.
All the connections are created in the initialization phase, and they are always open during the execution.
When the client needs some information, sends a request to all of the servers. Each server finds the information needed and answers to the client.

In the client there is a single thread that is in charge of receiving the messages from all of the sockets, in particular, I use only one `io_services`, and one async_read from each of the sockets.

When a message arrives in one of the sockets, the `async_read` read the first N bit that are the header of the message and than call a function that uses `read` (synchronous) to read the rest of the message. To the server side, the header and the rest of the message are sent with a single `write` (synchronous).

Then, the architecture works properly, but I noticed that sometimes the synchronous `read`takes more time (~0.24 sec) than the usual.
In theory the data is ready to be read because the synchronous `read` is called when the `async_read` has already read the header. I also saw that if I use only one server instead of 10, this problem doesn't occur. Furthermore, I noticed that this problem is not caused because of the dimension of the message.

Is it possible that the problem occurs because the `io_service` is not able to handle all the 10 `async_read`? In particular, if all the sockets receive a message at the same time, could the `io_service` lost some time to manage the queues and slows down my synchronous `read`?

I haven't posted the code, because is difficult to estract it from the project, but if you don't understand my description I could write an example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) When async.read completion handler gets invoked, it doesn't mean that some data is available, it means that all the available to that moment data *has already been read* (unless you specified a restricting completion-condition). So the subsequent sync.read might wait until some more data arrives.

2) Blocking a completion handler is a bad idea, because you actually block all the other completion handlers and other functors posted to that `io_service`. Consider changing your design.

Comment: First of all, thank you, than
1) OK, even if the server has finished its write, I can't assume that all the data is available, it makes sense.
2) Also this point, It makes sense. And probabily I can manage to use a async read also there.
But, if my `read` blocks the io_service, then read can be slow only because of a delay in the transmission of the data. Right?

Comment: @Daniele 1) "server finished its write" means it passed the data to tcp/ip stack, but then it takes some time to transmit the data over the network. 2) yes, `read` just waits until all the needed packets arrive (I don't know what completion-condition you set).

Answer (score 1):

If you go for an asynchronous design, don't mix in some synchronous parts. Replace all your synchronous reads and writes with asynchronous ones. Both reads and writes will block your thread while the asynchronous variants will not.

Further, if you know the number of expected bytes exactly after reading the header you should request exactly that number of bytes.

If you don't know it, you could go for a single `async_read_some` with the size of the biggest message you expect. `async_read_some` will notify you how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: I know the size of the message. In particular,I have an header of length "hL". The content of the header says me the length of the rest of the message. The `read` function that I used is in the following, and the completion condition is the size of the buffer.
boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(ptr, hL), boost::bind(&handle, this, error, bt));
I modified my code now and inside the `handle` function I have another `async_read` equal to the previous one except for the buffer. I have the same problems. Sometimes some requests, not always the same requests go slowly than usual.

Comment: did you replace ALL synchronous 'read' and 'write' by asynchronous ones? write might block you as well. do not call any function from the asynchronous handlers that might block (even a logger could block for some time). if you are blocked by a function you called, none of your handlers will be called.